# pkg_config_modules dependency fails because version in "Uncontrolled"

Tags: cmake, dependencies, version, versioning, dependency-management

## The Problem

I've got a `CMakeLists.txt` file with this content:

```
pkg_check_modules(FOO REQUIRED foo>=0.1.0.1)
```

When I run Cmake v3.17.2 with `cmake3 -G Ninja .` in that directory:

```
Checking for module 'foo>=0.1.0.1'
  Requested 'foo >= 0.1.0.1' but version of foo is Uncontrolled
```

## Details

- This is running inside RHEL7
- `yum info foo | grep Version` returns `Version  : 0.1.0.1.20200417git602d018`
- The *foo* module is created by the team I'm on

## The Question

How can I tell CMake what version my *foo* library is so that it isn't "Uncontrolled"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the output of the foo project, inside of the generated `lib64` directory, there's a `pkgconfig` directory which contains `foo.pc`.

Inside of that file, version info is as follows:

`Version: HEAD`

Change this to be the intended version. In my case this was automated by the build process of *foo*, so what was required was to add a git tag for the current version and rebuild.